# PHP Shows error when data inputted exist

Tags: php

I am currently learning PHP Programming,

I wanted to show error when the inputted data exists.
Can anyone show some example on how it doest work?

Here is code I used:

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  session_start();
  require '../database/database.php';

  // require '../database/inc_config2.php';
  require ('p_nav.php');

  if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
      header("Location: index.php");
      exit;
  }

  // select loggedin users detail
  $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
  $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);

  //Variable input data

  //include_once 'dbconfig.php';
  if(isset($_POST['btn-save']))
  {
      // variables for input data
      $pcat = $_POST['pcat'];

      if($pcat=='')  
      {  
          //javascript use for input checking  
          echo"<script>alert('Please enter Category')</script>";  

          //    echo 'Empty Category';
          header ("location:..\product\p_cat.php");
          exit();
      }  

      // variables for input data

      //check if category is exist
      //here query check weather if user already registered so can't register again.  
      $check_pcat_query="select * from pcategory WHERE pcat='$pcat'";  
      //    $check_user_query="select * from users WHERE user_name='$user_name'";
      $run_query=mysqli_query($dbcon,$check_pcat_query); 



      if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query)>0)  
      {  
          //echo "<script>alert('Category $pcat is already exist in our database, Please try another one!')</script>";  
          exit();  
      }  

      // sql query for inserting data into database
      //temporary disabled

      $sql_query = "INSERT INTO pcategory(pcat) VALUES('$pcat')";
      mysql_query($sql_query);   
      //echo "Supplier Added Successfully"; 
      //header ("location:..\product\index.php"); 

      exit(); 

      /*
      $insert_user="insert into pcategory (pcat) VALUE ('$pcat')";  
      if(mysqli_query($dbcon,$insert_user))  
      {  
          //  echo"<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>"; 
          echo "Welcome";
      }  */
  }

  // sql query for inserting data into database

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to search about it?

Comment: If you are just starting to learn PHP then please do yourself a favour and start using `mysqli` rather than the deprecated `mysql` - also, it seems that the first sql query is never really used - it is run but the result is not used. I see also there is a mix of `mysqli` and `mysql` functions being used.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error, you are using both MySQL and MySQLi, using both is fatal error if you work on live server. Just focus on MySQLi as MySQL is deprecated officially and is not supported anymore.

Now come to your question. Your logic seems to be fine a bit. This is how you have to implement:

1. Fetch values from FORM
2. First clean the input using mysqli_real_escape_string() function.
3. Use above values and check the record existance in the database (here use SELECT statement)
4. If mysqli_num_rows() gives you result greater than 0 than;
       (a) it means record already exists
       (b) else, execute INSERT statement

Comment: Hi thank you,

for this suggestion,

however i am not still familliar on how to use fetch from form

anyway i'll ask google how to do it so